# How to copy guide lines in The Gimp?

Tags: gimp, script-fu

Is it possible to copy guide lines from one image to another?
I need this because I have several images that need exactly the same composition, so I want to use the guide lines for this.
There's no option to select & copy a guide line, so I must add them manually.

It would be nice, if there's a little script-fu script.

Okay, there are some interesting functions I found:

```
(gimp-image-find-next-guide image index)
(gimp_image_add_hguide image xposition)
(gimp_image_add_vguide image yposition)
(gimp_image_get_guide_orientation image guide)
(gimp_image_get_guide_position image guide)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean copy guide lines from one image to another via script-fu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd really like to help you but I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Could you edit the question to provide more details?

At a guess (pending more information) are you looking for something like this?

```
guide = 0
while guide = gimp_image_find_next_guide (image_1,guide) != 0
     position = gimp_image_get_guide_position (image_1,guide)
     if gimp_image_get_guide_orientation (image_1,guide) == 0
          gimp_image_add_hguide (image_2,position)
        else
          gimp_image_add_vguide (image_2,position)
```

Note that this is pseudo-code, since the functions you mentioned seem to be part of an API that is using a syntax other than scheme-ish script fu.

But the first question is *what are you trying to accomplish?* -- after that we can worry about the details of how.

Comment: Could you please reanswer this question with _exactly_ this answer? I cannot accept your answer as the right answer. I want to finish this question and give you the right rep.

Comment: Done, but I"m not sure I understand why.

Comment: The bounty has run out without an accepted answer. So I cannot accept ANY answer as the correct one, even if your answer is the right one. I thought that if a new answer was posted I would be able to accept this new one. This was wrong, I contacted the SO-Team. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem, hope it worked out for you.  And thanks for following up regarding the scoring.  Should I delete the duplicate answer?

Answer (score 2):

Having been wanting to learn Gimp Scripts (PythonFu) for a while and requiring this functionality I used the Pseudo code provided by MarkusQ and this handy tutorial https://jacksonbates.wordpress.com/python-fu-gimp-scripting-tutorial-pages/ to create a script to copy guidelines from one image to another.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def CopyGuidelines(image_1, drawable, image_2):     
    guide = pdb.gimp_image_find_next_guide(image_1, 0)
    while guide != 0 :
        position = pdb.gimp_image_get_guide_position (image_1,guide)        
        if pdb.gimp_image_get_guide_orientation (image_1,guide) == 0:
            pdb.gimp_image_add_hguide (image_2,position)
        else:
            pdb.gimp_image_add_vguide (image_2,position)
        guide = pdb.gimp_image_find_next_guide (image_1,guide)      

register(
    "python-fu-CopyGuidelines",
    "Copy Guidelines",
    "Copy Guidelines from one image to another",
    "Anthony", "JustAGuyCoding", "2017",
    "Copy Guidelines",
    "", # type of image it works on (*, RGB, RGB*, RGBA, GRAY etc...)
    [
        (PF_IMAGE, "image_1", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Input layer", None),
        (PF_IMAGE, "image_2", "takes other image", None)
    ],
    [],
    CopyGuidelines, menu="<Image>/Tools")  

main()
```

You'll need to copy this in to a CopyGuidelines.py file and put it your Gimp's plugin directory (See Preferences > Folders ) and restart Gimp to see the CopyGuideline option under Tools. Then open up the two images, select the one with the Guidelines and select CopyGuidelines to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the script posted in the other answer to work, but if anyone else comes across this and needs the easy answer:

You can open the images, draw the guidelines on the first one, and then copy and paste the other images as new layers over the original. The guidelines will remain in place.